# MySQL Query to automatically populate permanent events into a table without repeating the input process

Tags: php, mysql, scheduling

I'm using MySQL dB and two tables are named "perm_events" for the repeated events and "reservations" to store the individual events that do not repeat, respectably. The "perm_events" table exists for the sole purpose of NOT having to type in the same information repeatedly. This is a question regarding the "perm_events".

For example:

- Event A: Scheduled to go on every Sunday, 8am to 9am indefinitely.
- Event B: Scheduled for every Tuesday, Thursday, between 12/1/2019 and 12/31/2019.

I'm using PHP UI to gather the information about events and I want to write a query base on the information collected from the UI.

Info gathered: (This will be stored in "perm_events" table.)

```
Event name: Event B
Location:   Rm. 1
Start time:  9:00AM
End Time:   10:00AM
Weekdays:   Tue, Thu
Start Date: 12/1/2019 (If NULL, the event is permanent)
End Date:   12/31/2019
```

Base on the collected info above, I want to populate a table containing the below:

```
   DATE    WKDAY EVENT NAME LOCATION STARTING_TIME ENDING_TIME 
---------- ----- ---------- -------- ------------- -----------
12/03/2019  TUE   EVENT B     Rm. 1    9:00AM        10:00AM
12/05/2019  THU   EVENT B     Rm. 1    9:00AM        10:00AM
12/10/2019  TUE   EVENT B     Rm. 1    9:00AM        10:00AM
12/12/2019  THU   EVENT B     Rm. 1    9:00AM        10:00AM   
                            .
                            . 
12/31/2019  TUE   EVENT B     Rm. 1    9:00AM        10:00AM
```

Currently, I am entering the ABOVE event as a series of events for the duration from 12/3/2019 through 12/31/2019, as the UI shown below (The below are stored in "reservations" table):

```
event_name: Event B(1)
location: Rm. 1
start_time: 9:00AM
end_time: 10:00AM
date: 12/3/2019
end_date: 12/31/2019
(Reserve Button)
```

After reserving this event, I'd go on to the next by repeating the process until the process is complete - as shown below.

```
event_name: Event B(2)
location: Rm. 1
start_time: 9:00AM
end_time: 10:00AM
date: 12/5/2019
end_date: 12/31/2019
(Reserve Button)
.
.
and so on...
```

I'd have to do this seemingly endless process until the process is complete (I think there are 8 or 9 in the above example). Moreover, for the permanent events that DO NOT have END DATES, I'd have to continually enter the same event information over-and-over again.

Simply put, I am looking to save time by **NOT** entering the event information repeatedly for an extended event or permanent event - one-by-one. It would be much more efficient process.

How do I go about doing this?

thank you in advance to all the experts who'll read my question.

Comment: So for each occurrence of such a repeating event, you insert a new record into your perm table? Then I don’t really get why you need two tables to begin with? What is _different_ between those two “types” of event then, that would justify two different tables?

Comment: _“How do I go about doing this?”_ - how you always go, if you don’t want to repeat yourself - you would use some sort of _loop_.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. First of all, you would not need two separate tables. I just wanted to show you that what I'm using currently, versus what I'm trying to achieve - I didn't want to mess up what is working perfectly fine. I thought perhaps create a query based on the info gathered from "perm_events" - this may be a User Interface, and insert data to the "reservations". When I eventually achieve what I'm aiming to do, I plan to merge two operations into one. This is not set in stone, I'm just looking for the best approach. I hope you understand my motive.

Answer (score 1):

I finally was able to solve the task with a help from Strawberry (many thanks to Strawberry).

I ended up NOT using MySQL query - rather, I utilized the "Bitwise Operator" to compare individual weekday-bits with combined week-bit, as introduced to me by Strawberry. (See code below with following comment:

// Compare bitwise operator(&) $wkDayBit(1 thru 127) and $daybit(pow(2,$i++)).)

The "Bitwise operator" technique was a key to solving this task.

the code below is a simplified version of what I'm using currently.

I hope the below will help someone who is in a similar situation.

```
<?php
  // Initialize variables.
  $wkDayBit  = 0;
  $count     = 1;
  $frmWkday  = array('Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat');
  $wkdays    = array('Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday');
  $wkDayBits = array(1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64);
  $permEvtArray = array();

  // Credit to HADI for the below function.
  function dateRange($first, $last, $step = '+1 day', $format = 'Y-m-d') {
    $dates   = array();
    $current = strtotime($first);
    $last    = strtotime($last);

    while ($current <= $last) {
      $dates[] = date($format, $current);
      $current = strtotime($step, $current);
    }
    return $dates;
  }

  if (isset($_POST['addPermEvent'])) {
    if (isset($_POST['wkday'])) {
      $ttlRep = 0;                        // Initialize the variable $ttlRep.
      $tmpWkDayBits = $_POST['wkday'];    // Assign array 'wkday' to $tmpWkDayBits.

      // Loop through the newly assigned $tmpWkDayBits using foreach loop
      foreach ($tmpWkDayBits as $row => $tmpWkDayBit) {
        $wkDayBit = $wkDayBit + $tmpWkDayBit;
      }
    }

    // Call function dateRange() & get all dates that are between start date and end  date.
    $dateRange = dateRange($_POST['stDate'], $_POST['endDate']);

    // Convert the bitwise integer to an array (Credit to Sammitch for this bit).
    for ($i=0; $i<7; $i++) {          // $i = loop 0 thru 6
      $daybit = pow(2,$i);            // 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64

      // Compare bitwise operator(&) $wkDayBit(1 thru 127) and $daybit(pow(2,$i++)).
      if ($wkDayBit & $daybit) {
        $newWkdays[]=$frmWkday[$i];
      }
    }

    // Increment $ttlRep with # days of dated perm events one at a time (e.g., #/$ttlRep)
    foreach ($dateRange as $rsvDate) {
      if (in_array(date('D', strtotime($rsvDate)), $newWkdays)) {
        $ttlRep ++;
      }
    }

    /*-----------------------------------------------------
    Compare to see if checked weekday(s), that is(are)
    in the date-range($dateRange) is in $newWkdays[] array. 
     +-----------------------------------------------------*/
    foreach ($dateRange as $rsvDate) {
      if (in_array(date('D', strtotime($rsvDate)), $newWkdays)) {

        // Add a counter to the event title.
        $eventTitle = $_POST['permEvTtl'] . " [" . $count . "/" . $ttlRep . "]";
        $count++;
    
        // Assign each event details to an array.
        $permEvt = [
          'eventTitle' => $eventTitle,                         // Text field
          "reservDate" => $rsvDate,                            // 2020-06-01 format
          "wkDay" => $wkdays[date('w', strtotime($rsvDate))],  // $wkdays['n']
          "reservTime" => date('g:i A', strtotime($_POST['stTime'])), // 8:00 PM
          "endTime" => date('g:i A', strtotime($_POST['endTime'])), // 8:00 PM format
          'userGr' => $_POST['userGr'],                             // Text field
          'rmReserv' => $_POST['rmReserv'],                         // Text field
          'reservCreated' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')  // 2020-06-01 22:32:06 format
        ];

        $permEvtArray[] = $permEvt;
      }
    }
  }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome">
  <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='assets/css/testCodes.css'>
  <title>Permanent Events Test Codes</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="permEvent-form">
  <form method="POST">
    <h3>BOOK PERM EVENT</h3>
  <div>
    <label for="permEvTtl">Perm Event Title:</label>
    <input type="text" name="permEvTtl" id="permEvTtl" required placeholder="Title"><br>
    <label for="rmReserv">Room/Loc:</label>
    <input type="text" name="rmReserv" id="rmReserv" required placeholder="Room"><br>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="stDate">Start/End Dates:</label>
    <input type="date" name="stDate" id="stDate" required>
    <input type="date" name="endDate" id="endDate" required>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="stTime">Start/End Times:</label>
    <input type="time" name="stTime" id="stTime" required>
    <input type="time" name="endTime" id="endTime" required>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="userGr">User Group:</label>
    <input type="text" name="userGr" id="userGr" required placeholder="Group"><br>
  </div>
  <div class="wkday_chk">
    <h3>Weekdays</h3>
    <?php for ($i=0; $i<7; $i++): ?>
      <input type="checkbox" name="wkday[]" id="<?php echo $frmWkday[$i]?>" value="<?php echo $wkDayBits[$i]?>">
      <label for="<?php echo $frmWkday[$i]?>"><?php echo $frmWkday[$i]?></label>
    <?php endfor ?>
  </div>
  <div class="permAdd_btn">
    <input type="submit" name="addPermEvent" value="ADD PERM EVENT">
  </div>
  </form>
</div>

<div class="reserv-table">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>DATE<br>WKDAY</th>
        <th>STA TIME<br>END TIME</th>
        <th>EVENT TITLE</th>
        <th>LOCATION<br>GROUP</th>
        <th>RESERVED ON</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <!-- loop through rm_reserved VIEW to populate Reservation table -->
      <?php if ($permEvtArray != NULL):?> 
        <?php foreach ($permEvtArray as $rsv):?>
          <tr>
            <td><strong><?php echo $rsv["reservDate"]."<br>".$rsv["wkDay"]?></strong></td>
            <td><?php echo $rsv["reservTime"]."<br>".$rsv["endTime"]?></td>
            <td><?php echo $rsv["eventTitle"]?></td>
            <td><?php echo $rsv["rmReserv"]."<br>".$rsv["userGr"]?></td>
            <td><?php echo "<strong>".$rsv["reservCreated"]?></td>
          </tr>
        <?php endforeach?>
      <?php endif ?>  
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Keith, I'm no coder, so this is just a proof of concept;

```
<?php

/* So let's say we store the days of the week as a bit integer, where 
   1 = Sunday, 2 = Monday, 4 = Wednesday, and 127 = everyday. For the 
   purposes of this example, I'm going to use Monday and Wednesday (2 and 8) which equals 10
*/

$weekday_bit = 10;

/*The following part is actually redundant if use the 'day' option of php's date() function, 
  but someone better at coding than me can show you how to do that...*/

$days = array('Sun','Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat');
$newdays = array(); //Initialise an array for storing the converted bit representation (so 'Mon','Wed', in this instance.

// Convert the bitwise integer to an array (Credit to Sammitch for this bit)

for( $i=0; $i<7; $i++ ) {
    $daybit = pow(2,$i);
    if( $weekday_bit & $daybit ) {
        $newdays[]=$days[$i];
    }
}

//And credit to HADI for what follows

function dateRange( $first, $last, $step = '+1 day', $format = 'Y-m-d' ) {
    $dates = array();
    $current = strtotime( $first );
    $last = strtotime( $last );

    while( $current <= $last ) {

        $dates[] = date( $format, $current );
        $current = strtotime( $step, $current );
    }

    return $dates;
}

$result = dateRange( '2019-11-01', '2019-11-31');

foreach($result as $v){
if(in_array(date('D', strtotime($v)),$newdays)){$x = 1;} else {$x = 0;}
echo $v." ".$x."<br>";
}

?>
```

Outputs, the following, where '1' represents every Monday and Wednesday in November

```
2019-11-01 0
2019-11-02 0
2019-11-03 0
2019-11-04 1
2019-11-05 0
2019-11-06 1
2019-11-07 0
2019-11-08 0
2019-11-09 0
2019-11-10 0
2019-11-11 1
2019-11-12 0
2019-11-13 1
2019-11-14 0
2019-11-15 0
2019-11-16 0
2019-11-17 0
2019-11-18 1
2019-11-19 0
2019-11-20 1
2019-11-21 0
2019-11-22 0
2019-11-23 0
2019-11-24 0
2019-11-25 1
2019-11-26 0
2019-11-27 1
2019-11-28 0
2019-11-29 0
2019-11-30 0
2019-12-01 0
```